# ADC not referencing to 4x fixed voltage referenced - PIC16F18854

Tags: pic, adc, voltage-reference, mplabx

I am using a [PIC16F18854](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001826B.pdf) with a stable VDD of 5.0V. Tried multiple chips.
Code has been primarily generated using MCC and verified with the datasheet.

Applicable registers:
ADREF: ADNREF = VSS, ADPREF = FVR_buf1
FVRCON: ADFVR = 4x, FVREN = enabled

- The ADC range appears to be VSS->VDD; changing VDD affects the ADC output
- The ADC acts as if it is being referenced to VDD (between 4.75V-6V)
- Changing just one bit of FVRCON to select to 2x or 1x works as expected - a reference 2.048V/1.024V and the ADC performs conversions. The output is stable when varying the supply voltage.

Could anything be leading to such an issue? Or a silicon/datasheet error?

Comment: I have fixed the formatting on your question but am unable to fix the question itself. Please re-read it from the point of view of someone who has no idea what you have done. Describe the problem (clearly) and the steps you have taken.

Comment: Are all of your supply pins properly decoupled? What is the source impedance of your input signal and how are you driving the ADC input?

Comment: I'm driving by a variable power supply directly through a 1k resistor (less than the 10k max source impedance as directed by the datasheet). It's puzzling as it all works perfectly on a 2x FVR reference, simply changing to 4x causes this issue. It is repeatable across chips.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to the above.

In my code, I had selected the channel, waited for the acquisition time (from the datasheet), then started the conversion using the function named "ADCC_StartConversion" generated by MPCC, which accepts the argument for a channel.

This function then re-selected the ADC channel and flags the ADC to begin "ADGO".

Despite the datasheet stating the requirement for an acquisition time, Microchip have implemented by MPCC, a function that will never work as designed.

Really, there should be an "ADC_SelectChannel" function and then an "ADC_StartConversion" so that the user can generate their own delay, or for the function to include the stated delay.

Comment: You can accept this as the correct answer to show that the problem is solved.